# sql server 2008 R2 cannot change default datetime format

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

My OS windows 10 home single language. The date format is dd-MM-yyyy While i am installing SQL Server 2008 R2 from my Laptop.

After that I have changed into mdy format by using the following command
DBCC useroptions
set language 'english'
Set DATEFORMAT mdy

But the datetime format error from my application  while insert data.

```
the conversion of varchar datatype to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value
```

I have convert date format like as below

```
  DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(datetime, "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
        dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"));
```

How to solved it

Comment: change ur machine date time and country region .

Comment: Your code seems incomplete (both in C# and SQL statement) - put related codes if necessary. Are you sure that the datetime value passed as `SqlDbType.DateTime`?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?  your c# code isnt making sense as datetime is a value not a format so converting it to string of MM-dd-yyyy and back to value serves no purpose

Comment: Yes i have changed us english

Comment: my datetimepicker format is dd-mm-yyyy, i have convert into MM-dd-YYYY format to insert database

Comment: Are you using `Text` property of the `DateTimePicker`? If it's true, I suggest you using `Value` property and pass the value directly as `DateTime` to datetime column in database using parameterized query, then you can display it as American date format. Again, I suggest you to include reproducible [mcve].

Comment: In sqlserver browser is in the format of YYYY-MM-DD has changed to YYYY-DD-MM after moving SQL Server to new server how do I switch back?